# Regular Expression to remove substring having at least 5 Uppercases

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a python list and I want a regular expression to remove substring which contains at least 5 uppercases. And another regex which could remove the part of string from ‘?’ till ‘:’

```
    INPUT : list = [‘helLo/aPPle/BuTTeRfLY:Missed’,’bliss/ScIENCEs/brew?Dyna=skjdk:Nest’,’Self/NESTeDsd/hello/MiSSInG:Good’]

    Output : list = [‘helLo/aPPle/:Missed’,’bliss//brew:Nest’,’Self//hello/:Good’]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here make 2 regex:**

1. (\w*[A-Z]\w*){5,} - find atleast 5 uppercase letters
2. ?.*(?=:) - find substring start with ? and end with :

- if we find string match with regex pattern then replace string with '' and update value in list

  ```
    import re

    reg =r'(\w*[A-Z]\w*){5,}|\?.*(?=:)'
    input_list = ["helLo/aPPle/BuTTeRfLY:Missed","bliss/ScIENCEs/brew?Dyna=skjdk:Nest","Self/NESTeDsd/hello/MiSSInG:Good"]

    for data in input_list:
        match = re.finditer(reg,data)
        if match:
            for match_word in match:
                print(match_word)
                if match_word.group() in data:


                    # if uppercase char >5 then replace this substring with ''
                    final_str = data.replace(str(match_word.group()),'')

                    # find index of data
                    index = input_list.index(data)
                    # replce new value in list
                    input_list[index] = data =final_str

    print(input_list)
  ```

**Output:** :- ['helLo/aPPle/:Missed', 'bliss//brew:Nest', 'Self//hello/:Good']